# Ascii character codes in C++ visual studio don't match up with actual character symbols?

Tags: c++, ascii

I am trying to represent 8 bit numbers with characters and I don't want to have to use an int to define the character, I want to use the actual character symbol. But when I use standard ASCII codes, everything outside of the range 32-100 something are completely different.

So I looped through all 256 ascii codes and printed them, for instance it said that this character '±' is code 241. But when I copy and paste that symbol from the console, or even use the alt code, it says that character is code -79... How can I get these two things to match up? Thank you!

Comment: ASCII is 0-127, fyi. `char` is also signed by default.

Comment: It is a problem of codepage probably. You need the CP ISO 8859-1 to have a 1:1 mapping between characters 0-255 to Unicode 0-255

Comment: @ChrisMM Whether `char` is signed or unsigned, is [implementation-defined](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#7).

Comment: Try SetConsoleOutputCP(28591). You'll need to include windows.h

Comment: @heapunderrun and in MSVC `char` is signed by default. There's nothing wrong with that

Comment: @heapunderrun, title says Visual studio, so I'm assuming CL and ML compiler, as opposed to VS code with a different compiler. VS uses signed char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a problem of codepage. Windows console applications have a codepage that "maps" the 0-255 characters to a subset of Unicode characters. It is something that exists from the pre-Unicode era to support non-american character sets. There are some Windows API to select the codepage for the console: `SetConsoleOutputCP` (and `SetConsoleCP` for input)

```
#include <iostream>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int cp = ::GetConsoleOutputCP();

    std::cout << "Default cp of console: " << cp << std::endl;

    ::SetConsoleCP(28591);
    ::SetConsoleOutputCP(28591);

    cp = ::GetConsoleOutputCP();

    std::cout << "Now the cp of console is: " << cp << std::endl;

    for (int i = 32; i < 256; i++) {
        std::cout << (char)i;

        if (i % 32 == 31) {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The 28591 codepage is the iso-8859-1 codepage that maps the 0-255 characters to the unicode 0-255 codepoints (the 28591 number is taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers)

Comment: So I tried that and now it correlates the ascii code to the right character, but it still does not correlate the character to the right code. When converting '±' to an int, it gives me -79 still.

Comment: @TristanAlexander `-79` is *signed* char `0xB1`, same as 177 if you consider it as unsigned. That's the correct code for `±` in both [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and the ANSI [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) codepages. The code you quoted `241` is what's used in the [OEM 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) codepage.

Comment: @dxiv Ah ok so is there any solution to my problem? Or do I have to use int to define everything? I think it is ridiculous how (char)('±' + 0)  doesn't equal '±', it equals a totally different character.

Comment: @dxiv Ok nvm it equals it with the stuff the other guy gave me. I think I see now 177 is just wrapping around to -79 and that's why the characters don't match u with the numbers.

Comment: @dxiv Also do you know that if multiplying or adding chars momentarily converts them to ints? Oh it totally does haha well whatever

Comment: @TristanAlexander If you want beautiful positive numbers (and I'll say that negative chars are really ugly), you can use `unsigned char`. Just try to NOT do: `for (unsigned char ch = 32; ch < 255; ch++)` because that is an infinite loop.